# Как при помощи Pyhton выгрузить все таблицы БД в один лист таблицы excel?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3

Есть код который у меня не работает, он постоянно перезаписывает на одном листе все что записывал на последующих итерациях, т.е каждая следующая таблица из базы перетирает записанную предыдущую, мне же необходимо дописывать смещаясь на 35 строчек вниз.Чтобы все таблицы из базы были выведены на 1 лист, одна за другой по вертикали.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook
import sqlite3
from ini import ini_stat
from open_file import read_list
from workdb import add_db



for i in read_list('k13.txt'):
  add_db(ini_stat(i))

connect = sqlite3.connect('kvm.db')
curs = connect.cursor()
curs.execute(f"SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table';")
mass_name_table = curs.fetchall() #двумерный массив с именами таблиц
my_path="/STORAGE/kvm/table.xlsx"

r,c = 1,0

with pd.ExcelWriter(my_path, engine='xlsxwriter') as my_obj:
    for i in mass_name_table:
        df = pd.read_sql(f"SELECT * FROM {i[0]}", connect)
        df.to_excel(my_obj, sheet_name='page1', startrow=r, startcol=c)
        r += 35

connect.close()
```

Помогите пжлст ).

Comment: Пробовали считать базы, объединить в один фрейм и один раз записать?

Comment: df.to_excel(my_obj, sheet_name='page1'... - может, это потому, что _вы говорите_ коду все писать на один лист? меняйте номер page при каждой итерации.

Comment: Записываю все в один page1, записывая в разные он запишет каждую таблицу базы в свой лист excel   мне надо что бы все было на 1

Comment: надо подумать на 1 фреймом.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо огромное Алексею Р навел на мысль о фрейме и все получилось.

```
   for i in mass_name_table:
        df = pd.read_sql(f"SELECT * FROM {i[0]}", connect)
        name_table.append(df)
        name_table.append(zero_fr)

    con_table = pd.concat(name_table, axis=0)
```